# How can I recover deleted text of MSWORD.docx file closed then reopened

Tags: microsoft-word

Mistakenly I closed my MS Word .docx document with deleting some text by error. When I reopened, I noticed what mistake i made.  I tried to get back my deleted work by Ctrl-Z (undo) but it diddnt work. I have not yet overwritten anything else in the doc and file is lying closed. Can anybody guide how can I recover my deleted text.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Changes are held in memory until you save the changes which you did not, that info is gone forever.

Comment: On Mac Time Machine or document history will have successive versions. idk if there's an equivalent on Windows.

Comment: I agree with @Moab . If your file is stored in OneDrive, online version history can help you see and restore older versions. For more information, read [Restore a previous version of a file stored in OneDrive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restore-a-previous-version-of-a-file-stored-in-onedrive-159cad6d-d76e-4981-88ef-de6e96c93893) and [View previous versions of Office files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-previous-versions-of-office-files-5c1e076f-a9c9-41b8-8ace-f77b9642e2c2).